# jquery fade in and out a background image in div - with cross fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, fadein

Have been attempting to have a background div auto rotate through a series of images.  The fades are flashing and not crossing.  Thoughts are to use jquery to swap out the image via css and fade the new one in.  A nice crossover might be nice.  This is fairly light weight - or so it seems and would rather not use a plugin.

Any insight on why were not getting a smoother crossover/transition?

```
    setInterval(delayFunction, 10000);

    function delayFunction() {

        setTimeout( function(){
        $('#homeback').fadeOut('slow');    
        $('#homeback').css("background-image","url(images/home_02.jpg)").fadeIn('slow');
    },5000);

        setTimeout( function(){
        $('#homeback').fadeOut('slow');    
        $('#homeback').css("background-image","url(images/home_03.jpg)").fadeIn('slow');
    },10000);

        setTimeout( function(){
        $('#homeback').fadeOut('slow');    
        $('#homeback').css("background-image","url(images/home_04.jpg)").fadeIn('slow');
    },15000);

        setTimeout( function(){
        $('#homeback').fadeOut('slow');    
        $('#homeback').css("background-image","url(images/home_01.jpg)").fadeIn('slow');
    },20000);

    };
```

Comment: You need to change the background image *after* the fadeOut has completed, no?

Comment: The application of a new background image and fadIN function are unrelated, what you're looking for is to overlay two images on top of each other and adjust each image's alpha channel simultaneously. I'm on my phone right now, but if this isn't answered tomorrow I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a simple example of a rotation check out my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yN8a/2/

The comments are right you need to adjust the background image AFTER the fadeout has completed and you do that by passing a second option that is used as a callback for when its done.

```
$(selector).fadeout('speed',function(){
     //execute your background switch then fade in.
});
```